# Is there a way for me to host my little ASP.Net project for free online?

Tags: hosting, asp.net

I have this little registration program.

I'm going to save 4 fields from the people who register. Name, RegistryNumber, Major, EMail. Nothing much, I know, this is just so people can register for an event my group has set up.

Is there a way for me to upload the simple ASP.Net project and the little database online, so anyone that wants to register can do some from home, **for free though?**

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why the vote to close? This is a programming related question. :S

Comment: I think this is much more relevant on stackoverflow than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.aspspider.com/ - seems to be free.

Comment: Yes - although my experience with them wasn't entirely positive...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Well, as 99% of the time shows, you get what you pay for!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really simplify your life, you could try any of the free, web based event registration services out there:  [This](http://www.techsoup.org/learningcenter/software/page7510.cfm) article gives a pretty good rundown of the major sites in this space. It wouldn't be as fun as building your own, but it might save you some headaches you'll encounter with some of the free hosting providers.

Answer (score 0):

https://freeasphosting.net/ and https://somee.com/default.aspx provide free hosting but **somee** provide it only for 6 month.